# how to take date/time value from user input (calendar selection) in Python

Tags: python, list, plotly-dash

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to capture my sensored data into a '**totalList**'. This is what I did:

```
  # Initialize data frame
df1 = pd.read_csv(
     "/Users/ME/Desktop/Frontend/sensor_points.csv",
    dtype=object,
)
df = pd.concat([df1], axis=0)
df["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df.index = df["Date/Time"]
df.drop("Date/Time", 1, inplace=True)
totalList = []
for month in df.groupby(df.index.month):
    dailyList = []
    for day in month[1].groupby(month[1].index.day):
        dailyList.append(day[1])
    totalList.append(dailyList)
totalList = np.array(totalList)
```

So, my problem is that the code believes that the value of month in the **month for-loop** will always iterate through 1, 2, ..., 12 and the **day for-loop** through 1,2,...,31. But those are not guaranteed. Because my CSV doesn't consist of data for all the months and days, for some dates on the calendar-picker I get an

> 'index-out-of-range' error for totalList

I know this is because in actuality, the shape of totalList strongly depends on the content of my input data (the CSV file). Let's say the file only contains records for 3 months (e.g. Jan. May and Dec.), then len(totalList)==3

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Is your problem when reading from the totalList or populating the totalList? If its from reading, you could just use a try/except or try/continue?

Comment: @Liza Darwesh could you give an example of what your .csv looks like?

Comment: @JasonChia When I open my calendar on the website I created, see updated picture above, I get this index out of range error, but only when I click on a date like 7 or 8 or something. When I click on 1 or 2 it shows the data just right. So the problem is I guess in the totalList I use

Comment: @VictorS I import a file with the data-format yy-mm-dd

Comment: @Liza Darwesh getting a different error. More than likely its because my data-format is different than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would then be on the access to TotalList from your website. (You are trying to access an index on your list that doesn't exist) You should simply include a try/except clause or method to handle the missing values. See the following example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[0]
1
>>> x[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> try:
...     x[4]
... except IndexError:
...     print("No such value exists")
...
No such value exists
```

Hope this helps. An alternative would be to presize your list/array and fill with some dummy variable and handle it in your accesses

```
>>> x = ["empty"]*4
>>> x[0] = 1
>>> x[1] = 2
>>> x[2] = 3
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, "empty"]
>>> x[0]
1
>>> x[3]
'empty'
```